# LEFT JOIN in MySQL gives same result as INNER or RIGHT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

In the following query, I am joining a samples table with 45324 items. The result gives me only 39426 and non of them containing empty SUM, SUM_YIELD or whatever... Could anyone explain why LEFT, RIGHT, and INNER JOINs give me the same outcome?

```
SELECT
  `gs_prod`.`samples`.`id` AS `id`,
  `gs_prod`.`samples`.`customer_name` AS `customer_name`,
  `qcs_demux_stats_view`.`sample_name` AS `sample_name`,
  FORMAT(
    SUM(`qcs_demux_stats_view`.`clusters`),
    0
  ) AS `SUM`,
  FORMAT(
    SUM(`qcs_demux_stats_view`.`yield`),
    0
  ) AS `SUM_YIELD`,
  ROUND(
    (
      SUM(
        (
          `qcs_demux_stats_view`.`perc_q30` * `qcs_demux_stats_view`.`clusters`
        )
      ) / SUM(`qcs_demux_stats_view`.`clusters`)
    ),
    2
  ) AS `perc_q30`
FROM
  (
    `gs_prod`.`qcs_demux_stats_view`
  JOIN
    `gs_prod`.`samples` ON(
      (
        `gs_prod`.`samples`.`id` = `qcs_demux_stats_view`.`sample_id`
      )
    )
  )
WHERE
  (
    `qcs_demux_stats_view`.`parent_id` IN(
    SELECT
      `gs_prod`.`qcs`.`id`
    FROM
      `gs_prod`.`qcs`
    WHERE
      (
        (`gs_prod`.`qcs`.`status` = 1) AND(
          `gs_prod`.`qcs`.`deleted` = 0
        )
      )
  ) AND(
    `qcs_demux_stats_view`.`status` = 1
  )
  )
GROUP BY
  `gs_prod`.`samples`.`id`,
  `qcs_demux_stats_view`.`sample_name`,
  `gs_prod`.`samples`.`customer_name`
```

So I'm getting a result like this:

```
id customer_name sample_name SUM SUM_YIELD perc_q30
41453 103312-001-005-BC105 103312-001-005-BC105 7 0 88.27 
41485 103312-001-005-BC137 103312-001-005-BC137 285 0 93.31
41517 103312-001-005-BC169 103312-001-005-BC169 270 0 91.46
```

But would also like to have lines like (where there is no data from qcs_demux_stats):

```
41517 103312-001-005-BC169 103312-001-005-BC169 0 0 NaN
```

The left 3 columns come from the samples table, the first one is the id that matches in the ON clause, and the right 3 columns are grouped data from qcs_demux_stats table.

Comment: if all the values in condition match then you have same result for inner , left and right join  ..  https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Yes, so in `gs_prod`.`samples`.`id` = `qcs_demux_stats_view`.`sample_id` you mean? but how could I have all the samples table items in the result and only the qcs_demux_stats results when they match? I thought this was, in this case, a right join...

Comment: Since you have a question regarding how your data looks like, you should provide some sample data from the underlying tables, the actual resultset you receive and the expected resultset that you expect to receive. Without these it is pretty hard to tell what could have gone wrong - if anything. The point is that you need to validate if the you have incorrect results in your current dataset before asking a question.

Comment: I edited and add some example output and wanted output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditions in the WHERE clause are requiring columns from `qcs_demux_stats_view` to be non-NULL,  which will cause an  OUTER join to be  equivalent to an INNER join.

One way to think about what an OUTER join does, how it operates...

When no matching row is found, the query generates a dummy row consisting of all NULL values. This dummy "matching" row allows the row to be returned.

If we include a requirement that a column from the dummy row be non-NULL, then that row will be excluded. That essentially throws out all of the generated dummy rows. Rendering the result equivalent to an inner join.

To get outer join results, either:

change the conditions in the WHERE clause to allow NULL values to be returned

or

relocate those conditions to the ON clause of the OUTER join

---

I recommend putting the the driving table on the left side, and write the query as a `LEFT` outer join. (Best to leave `RIGHT` outer joins as academic exercises.)

```
 SELECT s.`id`                           AS `id`
      , s.`customer_name`                AS `customer_name`
      , v.`sample_name`                  AS `sample_name`
      , FORMAT(  SUM(v.`clusters`) ,0)   AS `SUM`
      , FORMAT(  SUM(v.`yield`)    ,0)   AS `SUM_YIELD`

      , ROUND(   SUM( v.`perc_q30` * v.`clusters` )
               / SUM( v.`clusters` )
        ,2
        )                               AS `perc_q30`

   FROM `gs_prod`.`samples` s

   LEFT
   JOIN `gs_prod`.`qcs_demux_stats_view` v
     ON v.`sample_id` = s.`id`
    AND v.`parent_id` IN ( SELECT q.`id`
                             FROM `gs_prod`.`qcs` q
                            WHERE q.`status` = 1
                              AND q.`deleted` = 0
                         )
    AND v.`status` = 1

  GROUP
     BY s.`id`
      , v.`sample_name`
      , s.`customer_name`
```

This effectively says, get me all rows from `samples`, along with any matching rows from `qcs_demux_stats_view`.

If mo matching row is found in `qcs_demux_stats_view`, return the row from `samples` (the driving table on the LEFT side.) For those rows, the values of the columns from `qcs_demux_stats_view` will be NULL.

Comment: So, this learns me something! So is a right join much more difficult, or was it just that I had to use the extra conditions in the ON clause instead of the where clause?

Comment: Moving the conditions from the WHERE clause to the ON clause of the outer join fixed the problem.  Using a `RIGHT` join would work, the query in my answer could be changed, swapping the two table references, and replacing `LEFT` keyword with the keyword `RIGHT`. It's just that no one ever does that, there's no point. it can be written as a LEFT join, with the driving table on the left side. That's the pattern everyone uses. The two forms are equivalent i.e. the right join has no advantage. And no advantage to two patterns when one suffices. So `LEFT` wins, it's just what we do.

Comment: Leave writing `RIGHT` outer joins to the academics, where bonus points are awarded for it. As long as we know how to re-write `RIGHT` joins as `LEFT` joins, we can eschew academic obfuscation. (That's how my brain works with RIGHT joins... it re-writes them as a LEFT join so I can understand it.)